# passing a parameter between two QWidget forms in QT

Tags: qt, parameter-passing, qwidget

I'm new to QT and i'm trying to pass a parameter between two forms but i'm not able to do that ..could anybody help me please by giving me a simple example of passing a string constant "parameter" from main window to another QWidget 0 window called results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new class, let's say `MyWidget`, derived from QWidget or QDialog, how you want it, create slot in it - `setText(QString txt)` or however you like. Then in your MainWindow class, create instange of `MyWidget` -

```
... code that leads to moment, where you want to create another widget
MyWidget* wg=new MyWidget();
wg->setText("And that's all the magic"); // you pass text to that widget's slot setText(), where you use it however you like
```

**EDIT**:

to display text in a label, your slot `setText(QString txt)` in class `MyWidget` should be something like this:

```
MyWidget::setText(QString txt){
    myLabel->setText(txt); // myLabel is Qlabel, that you created in MyWidget class    
}
```

Comment: then how can i display it in a label?

Comment: i tried what did u said but i still have this error :( what's matter ?

 'class MyWidget' has no member named 'setText'

Comment: well, you need to add new class to your project ( project -> add new -> c++ class -> select QWidget as parent) and in header file (MyWidget.h) inside class declaration add lines `public slots:` and `void setText(Qstring txt)` right after it

Comment: Qt forces developer to code right - class consists of source (.cpp) and header file (*.h)

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what you are asking here, since I think this is quite straightforward, but here is the complete code for header file:

```
#ifndef CMAINWINDOW_H
#define CMAINWINDOW_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>

/* this is your dialog with results.
   It contains one label to show the value of parameter passed in. */
class CResults : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    CResults(const QString & text = QString(), QWidget *parent = 0);

    void setText(const QString & text);

  private:
    QLabel *m_lbl;
};

/* This is your main top-level window which contains two push buttons.
   Each of them triggers one dialog and passes a different parameter to it. */
class CMainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    CMainWindow(void);


  private slots:
    void onDialog1BtnClick(void);
    void onDialog2BtnClick(void);

  private:
    QPushButton *m_pb_dlg1;
    QPushButton *m_pb_dlg2;
    CResults *m_dlg1;
    CResults *m_dlg2;
};

#endif // CMAINWINDOW_H
```

and here is the implementation:

```
#include "CMainWindow.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>

CResults::CResults(const QString & text, QWidget *parent)
  : QDialog(parent)
{
  m_lbl = new QLabel(text, this);
}

void CResults::setText(const QString & text)
{
  m_lbl->setText(text);
}


CMainWindow::CMainWindow(void)
 : QWidget(0)
{
  /* The following line shows one way of passing parameters to widgets and
     that is via constructor during instantiation */
  m_dlg1 = new CResults("parameter", this);
  m_dlg2 = new CResults(QString(), this);
  m_pb_dlg1 = new QPushButton("Dialog1", this);
  connect(m_pb_dlg1, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(onDialog1BtnClick()));
  m_pb_dlg2 = new QPushButton("Dialog2", this);
  connect(m_pb_dlg2, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(onDialog2BtnClick()));

  QVBoxLayout *l = new QVBoxLayout(this);
  l->addWidget(m_pb_dlg1);
  l->addWidget(m_pb_dlg2);

  setLayout(l);
}

void CMainWindow::onDialog1BtnClick(void)
{
  m_dlg1->exec();
}

void CMainWindow::onDialog2BtnClick(void)
{
  /* In this case you want to override the default value passed to constructor,
     so you will use the setter function */
  m_dlg2->setText("Something random");
  m_dlg2->exec();
}
```

If you meant something else, please be more specific so that I can adjust my answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer,, as i said i'm so new on qt and i wish if u can comment the code above so i will know what does each of the added code (u added it) means. i will appreciate your help heavily cause i'm suffering and i have no time. what i meant by my question is to have a simple example of passing a string parameter in the main window let's say it's from text edit and i want it to be displayed in a second form label.. could u help me please?

Comment: @NermeenoAlami sorry about the comments, basically what I did was that I created a setter function for the Results dialog and called this function to set the parameter of the dialog before showing it. 

I admit that the answer is quite involved for such a simple problem, but I wanted the code to compile out of box, so that you can experiment with it (you just have to instantiate `CMainWindow` class somewhere in `main()` and that's it).

The response from Shf may be better comprehensible though.